# How to delete N numbers of documents in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

In my collections, documents contains key like status and timestamp. When I want to find latest ten documents then I write following query

```
db.collectionsname.find().sort({"timestamp"-1}).limit(10)
```

This query gives me results which I want but when I want to delete latest ten documents then I was writing the following query

```
db.collectionsname.remove({"status":0},10).sort({"timestamp":-1})
```

but it shows following error 
    `TypeError: Cannot call method 'sort' of undefined`
and again I wrote the same query as below 
    `db.collectionsname.remove({"status":0},10)`
It deletes only one document. So how can I write a query which deletes ten latest documents and sorts on timestamp?

Comment: That might help you http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You can't set a limit when using `remove` or `findAndModify`. So, if you want to precisely limit the number of documents removed, you'll need to do it in two steps.

```
db.collectionName.find({}, {_id : 1})
    .limit(100)
    .sort({timestamp:-1})
    .toArray()
    .map(function(doc) { return doc._id; });  // Pull out just the _ids
```

Then pass the returned `_id`s to the remove method:

```
db.collectionName.remove({_id: {$in: removeIdsArray}})
```

FYI: you cannot remove documents from a capped collection.

Comment: Who do you have to do the sort part if all the records are going to be deleted?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it makes difference whether `limit(100)` comes before `sort({timestamp:-1})` or after. In the example @WiredPrairie limits results to 100 and sorts them afterwards (`.sort({timestamp:-1}).limit(100)`). In this case the sorting statement has no effect on the records returned. On the other hand, if you would write `.limit(100).sort({timestamp:-1})`, it would make a difference.

Comment: @ULazdins "Mongo applies the sort before limiting the results regardless of the order you call sort and limit on the cursor." ([source](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17509131/99777))

Comment: what if the numbers is large? I got the error : "Converting from JavaScript to BSON failed: Object size 19888938 exceeds limit of 16793600 bytes. "

Answer (score 32):

You can pipeline the output of find query mapping to use `_id` and performing a remove based on `$in` query such as:

```
db.collection.remove({_id: 
    { $in: db.collection.find().sort({timestamp:-1}).limit(100).map(a => a._id) }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, this works on mongo command line client too

Comment: Using the new mongo shell `mongosh` on MongoDB 5.0 this returns the following error `Error: cyclic dependency detected`

Comment: The cyclic dependency goes away if you add in `.toArray()` before `.map`.

Answer (score 25):

Let N be number of records to delete.

```
    db.collectionName.find().limit(N).forEach(doc => 
     { 
       db.collectionName.remove({_id:doc._id})
     }
    )
```

Comment: Although this will technically work, it will result in multiple remove calls to mongo. Better send it in one batch like the selected answer

Comment: congratulations, now you have N + 1 db call.

Comment: Its still a useful answe. For example:- When you have large number of documents in a dev db and you simply want to keep only lets say 2mi out of 4mi, you can leave it to work overnight to run cleanups, instead of printing 2mi _id's and then supplying them (most probably in batches)

Answer (score 14):

To remove N number of documents in your collection `myCollection`:

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').find({}).limit(N).forEach(function(doc){
    db.getCollection('myCollection').remove({_id: doc._id});
})
```

Comment: This worked quite nice for me in Robo 3T in contrast to the accepted answer.

Comment: I logged in to upvote this. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

**Working solution** (Inspired by answers above):

(For deleting Huge amount of records the `$in` operator has a limitation so this is the ultimate solution)
Example for deleting 1,000,000 records

```
var ITERATIONS=1000;
var LIMIT=1000;
for(i=0; i<ITERATIONS; i++) {
    arr = db.MyCollection.find({}, {_id : 1}).limit(LIMIT).toArray().map(function(doc) { return doc._id; });
    db.MyCollection.remove({_id: {$in: arr}});
    // sleep(1);  // Optional for not loading mongo in case of huge amount of deletions
}
```

**You can run this in mongo shell or in Robomongo 3T**

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach:

Step 1: Sort and limit and $out documents in temporary collection

```
db.my_coll.aggregate([
  { $sort: { _id: - 1} },
  { $limit: 10000 },
  { $out: 'my_coll_temp' }
])
```

Step 2: Remove (Not dropping since, this preserves indexes) all the documents from the original collection. Also this step is what might make this approach less versatile since, removing might not always be possible.

```
db.my_coll.remove({})
```

Step 3: Move back the documents from temporary collection to original collection

```
db.my_coll_temp.aggregate([ { $out: 'my_coll' } ])
```

Step 4: Drop the temporary collection

```
db.my_coll_temp.drop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I find is:

```
        let uid = "your_user";

        let a = await db
          .collection(`notifications`)
          .find({
            owner: uid,
          })
          .sort({ _id: -1 })
          .skip(1000)
          .limit(1)
          .toArray();

        if (a.length > 0) {
          let _id = new ObjectId(a[0]._id);
          db.collection(
            `notifications`
          ).deleteMany({
            owner: uid,
            _id: { $lt: _id },
          });
        }
```

Explanation: The 'a' variable get the _id of the last entry you want to delete olders. You can specify what n value by using 'skip'. Example: You have 5000 entries but you wanna stay with 400 new ones, just set skip to '400'. In this case we are sorting by _id, but you can use what you want. You can use find to filter results to match exactly what you need.

The second half of algorithm do the delete. Use the same filter (owner:uid) to match the first find, and delete many less than "_id".

You also use a 'count' if statement before this code block to check if it is necessary, to avoid server coasts.

Answer (score -1):

Another way is to write a python script.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

def main():
    local_client = MongoClient()
    collection = local_client.database.collection
    cursor = collection.find()
    total_number_of_records = 10000

    for document in cursor:
        id = document.get("_id")

        if total_number_of_records == 100:
            break

        delete_query = {"_id": id}
        collection.delete_one(delete_query)

        total_number_of_records -= 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # execute only if run as a script
    main()
```

Answer (score -8):

Below query will find and delete the latest 10 documents from collection:-

```
db.collectionsname.findAndModify({
    query: { 'status':0 },
    sort: { 'timestamp': -1 },
    limit: 10,
    remove: true
});
```

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/

This doesn't support a "limit" field, and in fact if you try it, you will find it only deletes 1 element (as that is the default logic)

Answer (score -8):

query sql is

```
db.order.find({"业务员姓名" : "吊炸天"},{"业务员编号":0}).sort({ "订单时间" : -1 })
```

the result is

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5c9c875fdadfd961b4d847e7"),
"推送ID" : "248437",
"订单时间" : ISODate("2019-03-28T08:35:52Z"),
"订单状态" : "1",
"订单编号" : "20190328163552306694",
"业务员姓名" : "吊炸天"
}
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5c9c875fdadfd961b4d847e8"),
"推送ID" : "248438",
"订单时间" : ISODate("2019-03-28T08:35:52Z"),
"订单状态" : "1",
"订单编号" : "20190328163552178132",
"业务员姓名" : "吊炸天"
}
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5c9c875fdadfd961b4d847e5"),
"推送ID" : "248435",
"订单时间" : ISODate("2019-03-28T08:35:51Z"),
"订单状态" : "1",
"订单编号" : "20190328163551711074",
"业务员姓名" : "吊炸天"
}
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5c9c875fdadfd961b4d847e6"),
"推送ID" : "248436",
"订单时间" : ISODate("2019-03-28T08:35:51Z"),
"订单状态" : "1",
"订单编号" : "20190328163551758179",
"业务员姓名" : "吊炸天"
}
```

now delete the 3 and 4 data

```
var name = ["吊炸天"]
var idArray = db.order.find({"业务员姓名" : {$in:name}},{"订单编号":1,})
                .sort({ "订单时间" : -1 })
                .skip(2)
                .map(function(doc){return doc.订单编号})

db.order.deleteMany({"订单编号":{$in:idArray}})
```

return result is

```
{
"acknowledged" : true,
"deletedCount" : 2
}
```