# MongoDB - Remove Objects From Collection

Tags: mongodb

How do I remove all but the first n objects from a collection in MongoDB? For example, I only want to keep the first 2000 objects in my collection, but at the moment, there are 15000 objects.

EDIT: My question is more generalized than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19065615/how-to-delete-n-numbers-of-documents-in-mongodb) related question. Not a duplicate.

Comment: Related question [How to delete N numbers of documents in mongodb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19065615/how-to-delete-n-numbers-of-documents-in-mongodb).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could select the IDs of the first `N` documents (that you want to keep):

```
var ids = [];
db.collection.find().limit(N).toArray().map(function(doc){
    ids.push(doc._id);
});
```

Then, you perform the following query:

```
db.collection.remove({_id:{$nin:ids}})
```

This removes every tuple whose id is NOT in the array `ids`. For further information about `$nin` (i.e., "not in") operator see [this link](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/).

Comment: Nice solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered **capped collection** with **max** parameter?
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/

> db.createCollection("log", { capped : true, max : 2000 } );

If you really are just looking to delete all but 2000 newest objects, you could find the _id and remove everything `$lt` than _id.

Comment: At that point he would have something not fully manageable. Notice that you cannot delete documents from a capped collection! That would be a fixed size collection.

Comment: And you are right. However, user asked: `I only want to keep the first 2000 objects in my collection` - hence capped collection.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Your solution works fine if then that collection is (allowed me the term) "dead", i.e., he won't modify its size. If he wants to do something more -after- the shrinking, then another solution may be needed.

Comment: In this case, Eleanore is right. The collection isn't set-in-stone so to speak, but I appreciate the extra suggestion (and I learned something in the process).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for here, I just didn't know the term. Thank you!