# Why mongo does not support skip and limit for deleting the matched documents?

Tags: java, mongodb

Are there any other alternates in Java to achieve the same **in single query** in aggregate or something? I checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19065615/how-to-delete-n-numbers-of-documents-in-mongodb) but it still has two queries to be executed.

Example:

```
 db.test.remove({"type":"xyz"}).skip(500)
```

Something like this is not possible because Mongo DB does not allow skip and limit for remove. It shows error as follows.

```
TypeError: Object WriteResult({ "nRemoved" : 10 }) has no method 'skip' at (shell):1:32
```

If I have to purge some logs, I have to execute multiple queries one for finding the sorted nth element's _id (when I have to skip n) and then have a $lt or $gt query to delete anything before/after that time.

Is there any other provisions to reduce the number of queries executed?

Comment: Hi Sree Karthik S R; can you give an example of what it is you're trying to do, and what specific problems you are getting?

Comment: Hi Vince Bowdren, have updated the question. Any help is appreciated.