# Can't get limit to work in mongojs nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongojs

my code only works if i remove the limit function, what im doing wrong?

```
var db = mongojs('yansite', ['yansite']);
(function () {
    var bulk = db.ips.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
    bulk.find({}).limit(2).remove();
    bulk.execute(function (err, res) {
        console.log('Done!')
    });
})();
```

error is:

> TypeError: bulk.find(...).limit is not a function
>       at D:\nodeprojects\mysite\server.js:281:19
>       at Object. (D:\nodeprojects\mysite\server.js:285:3)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
>       at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
>       at run (bootstrap_node.js:390:7)
>       at startup (bootstrap_node.js:150:9)

in mongojs github README it shows this example:

> db.mycollection.find({}).limit(2).skip(1, function (err, docs) { ...
>   })

Comment: `limit` can't be used with `remove`. Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19065615/how-to-delete-n-numbers-of-documents-in-mongodb

Comment: i just tried without bulk and find limit does work gotta be a way to bulk no?, i saw that solution i just dont get how it works where it returns to so i can delete? , the removeIdsArray hasnt been set in there

Comment: find limit works, sure, but not with remove.

Comment: need that remove though

Answer (score 0):

i did it but kinda ugly i wish there was a way, its hard to believe there isn't

```
(function () {
    db.usersChatMessages.find({}).limit(2, function (err, doc) {
        console.log('Done!');
        var docIds = [];
        for (var i=0; i < doc.length; i++) {
            docIds.push(doc[i]._id);
        }
        db.usersChatMessages.remove({_id: {$exists: true, $in: docIds}}, function (err, doc) {
            console.log('removed!');
        });
    });
})();
```