# How can I remove N documents in PyMongo?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to `collection.remove({})` N documents using PyMongo.
On mongodb this is done like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19065615/how-to-delete-n-numbers-of-documents-in-mongodb), what's the PyMongo equivalent?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to remove N documents in a collection, you can do

1. A `bulk_write` of `DeleteOne` operations on the collection. *e.g.*

   ```
   In [1]: from pymongo import MongoClient
           from pymongo.operations import DeleteOne


           client = MongoClient()
           db = client.test
           N = 2 

           result = db.test.bulk_write([DeleteOne({})] * N)

   In [2]: print(result.deleted_count)
   2
   ```
2. A `delete_many` using a filter of all ids from a previous `find`. *e.g.*

   ```
   def delete_n(collection, n):
       ndoc = collection.find({}, ('_id',), limit=n)
       selector = {'_id': {'$in': [doc['_id'] for doc in ndoc]}}
       return collection.delete_many(selector)

   result = delete_n(db.test, 2)
   print(result.deleted_count)
   ```