# Mongoid delete many with limit

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

Using mongoid, how to delete the first 10000 documents where the `error_message` field is: `Error: not found`.

Native mongo queries will be happily accepted

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19066328/5648253

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB support limit on delete.

> The delete command removes documents from a collection. A single
>   delete command can contain multiple delete specifications

```
{
   delete: <collection>,
   deletes: [
      { q : <query>, limit : <integer>, collation: <document> },
      { q : <query>, limit : <integer>, collation: <document> },
      { q : <query>, limit : <integer>, collation: <document> },
      ...
   ],
   ordered: <boolean>,
   writeConcern: { <write concern> }
}
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/delete/#dbcmd.delete

where 'q' is your query with your specific input data (that must match the documents you want to delete) and 'limit' is the number of max documents to delete. As you can see, there is the possibility to have multiple delete conditions but is out of the scope of your question.

Comment: I wonder if Mongoid supports it. It can be a good feature request, if not.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh according with MongoDB documentation 'delete' is supported by 'runCommand'. Then you should call 'runCommand' with Ruby (https://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/moped/Moped%2FSession%3Acommand) to use it.

Comment: From docs: limit - The number of matching documents to delete. Specify either a 0 to delete all matching documents or 1 to delete a single document.
You can't set number of documents to delete.