# deleting records mongo db in collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How can I use below script for deleting 5K records:

```
db.transaction.deleteMany({
  "timeStamp": { $gte: new Date(2018, 0, 1), $lt: new Date(2019, 0, 1) }
})
```

I tried with finding first in collection, but it's saying 0 records fetched.

```
db.transaction.find({
  "timeStamp": { $gte: new Date(2018, 0, 1), $lt: new Date(2019, 0, 1) }
})

Output: Fetched 0 record(s) in 31ms
```

But i checked in collection below records with these timestamp are present,

"timeStamp" : ISODate("2018-12-31T18:30:03.379Z"),

"timeStamp" : ISODate("2018-12-31T18:30:03.982Z"),

Comment: doesn't it work as-is?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongoid delete many with limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51917027/mongoid-delete-many-with-limit)

Comment: You code above looks good on my local machine. What is the type of `timeStamp` in your collection? One problem I met before was my existing data in the collection was `Date` type while my client side uses `String` type for newly inserted data, which causes unexpected behavior when sorting by that field.

Comment: Having more then 10 Lakh records  in collection, so need to delete 5K records to overcome load on DB...how to use above script for tht.

Comment: Hi Experts,I need to delete 5K records from the above  script, how can i use it: db.transaction.deleteMany({
  "timeStamp": { $gte: new Date(2018, 0, 1), $lt: new Date(2019, 0, 1) }
})     :- in my collection it's timestamp only with field.