# Query for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How to remove a document in MongoDB where I want to remove id 1 to 1000, In the collection, I have 10 million documents.

```
db.posts.remove(
 { "id": 1 to 1000}
 )
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete N numbers of documents in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19065615/how-to-delete-n-numbers-of-documents-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db.posts.remove({"id": { "$gte": 1, "$lte":1000 }});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the command below on shell

```
db.posts.deleteMany({$and: [{"id": { $gte: 1} }, {"id": { $lte: 1000} }] )
```

For reference, you can also visit [MongoDocs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.deleteMany/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query

```
db.posts.remove({"$and" : [{"id" :{"$gte" :1}},{"id" :{"$lte" :1000}}]})
```