# How to perform mongoose deleteMany() with query operators?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I want to delete X number of posts starting from the *most recently created* for a specific user.

How can I apply this logic using mongoose so that I can perform just ONE database operation instead of first having to query for these posts and remove them one by one?

I am finding using the query and projection operators with the $ very confusing, any help would be appreciated.

Below I added pseudo code on how it should to work.

Thank you!

```
const userId = "123456"
const deleteCount = 6

const deletedPosts = await Post.deleteMany({
      .where { userid == userId) }
      .sort({createdAt: -1}) // delete by most recent
      .limit(deleteCount)    // only delete 6 (most recent) posts
      }, {new: true})        // return results of operation

console.log(deletedPosts.deletedCount) // -> should be "6"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19065615/how-to-delete-n-numbers-of-documents-in-mongodb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set a limit when using deleteMany or findAndModify. So, if you want to precisely limit the number of documents removed, you'll need to do it in two steps.

1. `db.getCollection('users').find({}, {class : 4}) .limit(2) .sort({StudentAge: -1}) .toArray() .map(function(doc) { return doc._id; }); //returns the array of id's`
2. `db.getCollection('users').deleteMany({_id: {$in: [ "s3", "s4" ]}})//put the array of id's`

[image: Data in model]

[image: 1st query]

[image: 2nd query]

[image: Final output]